# How to properly remove resource object completely?

Tags: resourceobject

Suppose I get some `resourceObject`:

```
resourceObject=ResourceObject[...]
```

Next, I download a local copy of its data:

```
resourceData=ResourceData[resourceObject]
```

Now I look at the places in my system where it has made modifications:

```
LocalCache[resourceObject]
resourceObject["ResourceLocations"]
resourceObject["ContentElementLocations"]
```

If I try to remove it:

```
ResourceRemove[resourceObject]
```

Then I can see that

```
resourceObject["ResourceLocations"]
resourceObject["ContentElementLocations"]
```

have been deleted but `LocalCache[resourceObject]` still remains.

So what am I doing wrong?

Also when I download its example notebook where is it stored?

```
resourceObject["ExampleNotebook"]
```